# how to get Instagram API profile(imgUrl,userId,...) other users without connecting to facebook or not using instagram_business_account?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

When I use API Instagram Basic Display, It is only for Instagram Testers , so I decide to use Instagram Graph API but the users have to connect manually their facebook pages to Instagram pages first. I just want the users login into my app and I can get their Instagram profile (userId, profile picture, username,...) , please help me !

I tried doing same as videos on youtube, reading Meta documments but I can't resolve it